# How to set the NSManagedObjectContext for MR_findFirst?

Tags: core-data, ios7, magicalrecord-2.2

I use MagicalRecord for my CoreData store.  I have a statement that is generating multiple crashes by different users when this statement is executed:

```
PreferenceData *prefDataFound = [PreferenceData MR_findFirst];
```

The error is:

> +entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'PreferenceData'

coming from this sequence of calls (from Crashlytics):

```
1   libobjc.A.dylib objc_exception_throw + 30
2   CoreData +[NSEntityDescription entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] + 104
3   SalonBook NSManagedObject+MagicalRecord.m line 91
    +[NSManagedObject(MagicalRecord) MR_entityDescriptionInContext:]
4   SalonBook NSManagedObject+MagicalRequests.m line 19
    +[NSManagedObject(MagicalRequests) MR_createFetchRequestInContext:]
5   SalonBook NSManagedObject+MagicalFinders.m line 79
    +[NSManagedObject(MagicalFinders) MR_findFirstInContext:]
6   SalonBook NSManagedObject+MagicalFinders.m line 86
    +[NSManagedObject(MagicalFinders) MR_findFirst]
7   SalonBook SubViewGrid.m line 37
    -[SubViewGrid drawRect:]
```

All of this indicates to me that there is no valid *context* for the MR_findFirst call; oher than using *MR_findFirstWithPredicate:* (for which I have no predicate, I just want the first and only record), what can I do to fix this?

Comment: That's what I don't like about Magical Record. There is to much magic with threads and contexts. - If you have a current context then you could call `[PreferenceData MR_findFirstInContext:context]` instead.

Comment: Martin R: please rewrite your comment as an answer.  I looked and wasn't even aware of this method.  Thank you, I think this will do the trick!  SD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call

```
PreferenceData *prefDataFound = [PreferenceData MR_findFirstInContext:context];
```

with your current context, instead of relying on Magical Record to determine the
current context magically.